# Without anything vs without everything?

Tags: negation

What's more correct in English: `without anything` or `without everything`? (in meaning 'total negation')

Sample:

> It's asp.net core 2.1 app without everything (without web API, without
>   MVC, without razor pages, just emptiest app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"without anything" means with nothing, whereas "without everything" means without a number of specific things, or the usual things that come with something.